How do I access non-python files using directories in Python for the whisper library?
I'm trying to make an auto video app using the whisper module. I can't figure out how to access non-python files in python.
Code is here:
import whisper # type: ignore
model = whisper.load_model("base")
result = model.transcribe("./AutoYoutubeVid/TestThing.mp3")
print(f' The text in video: \n {result["text"]}')

I've looked stuff up, nothing helpful. I've tried saying TestThing.mp3, AutoYoutubeVid/TestThing.mp3 the full directory, and what was in the code block, but it all gave me an error basically saying it couldn't find the file. I have checked that the file is in that exact directory, and it was.
Here is the error:

C:\Users\CENSORED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py:115:
UserWarning: FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead
warnings.warn("FP16 is not supported on CPU; using FP32 instead")
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"c:\Users\CENSORED\OneDrive\Desktop\Python
Projects\AutoYoutubeVid\Auto make a youtube video thing idk man.py",
line 4, in 
result = model.transcribe("AutoYoutubeVid/TestThing")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\CENSORED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py",
line 122, in transcribe
mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio, model.dims.n_mels, padding=N_SAMPLES)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File
"C:\Users\CENSORED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py",
line 140, in log_mel_spectrogram
audio = load_audio(audio)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\CENSORED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py",
line 58,  in load_audio
out = run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True).stdout
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\CENSORED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py",
line 548, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\CENSORED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py",
line 1026, in init
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File
"C:\Users\CENSORED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py",
line 1538, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
specified


The problem isn't that it can't find the mp3 file -- it can't find the ffmpeg program executable.  Do you have ffmpeg installed?
